# How to find out right away when a new Uniswap Pool is created with liquidity

Tags: uniswap

I want to find out whenever a new Uniswap pool is created and funded with an at least .5 ETH of liquidity. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work with QuickNode

You can track these events using [QuickAlerts](https://www.quicknode.com/quickalerts) and get realtime notification as soon as they occur.
You have to track the topic0 hash of the event + the smart contract address.
Let me explain how:

- For Uniswap v2. You'd have to track Topic0 of the `PairCreated` event which is `0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9`
- For Uniswap v3, You'd have to track Topic0 of the `PoolCreated` event which is `0x783cca1c0412dd0d695e784568c96da2e9c22ff989357a2e8b1d9b2b4e6b7118`

Then the Factory smart contract needs to be tracked too,

- Factory contract for Uniswap v2: `0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f`
- Factory contract for Uniswap v3: `0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984`

Learn how to setup QuickAlerts here:

1. Using the GUI, [Docs](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/getting-started) [Guide](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/quickalerts/an-overview-of-quicknodes-quickalerts) [Video](https://youtu.be/Y3UZDxX-ZD8)
2. Using the REST API, [Docs](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/rest-api/getting-started) [Video](https://youtu.be/XNdPkH7xHG8)

The expression to track would be the events would be,

**For Uniswap v2**,

```js
(tx_value >= 500000000000000000) && (tx_logs_address == '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f') && (tx_logs_topic0 == '0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9')
```

**For Uniswap v3**,

```js
(tx_value >= 500000000000000000) && (tx_logs_address == '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984') && (tx_logs_topic0 == '0x783cca1c0412dd0d695e784568c96da2e9c22ff989357a2e8b1d9b2b4e6b7118')
```

**For both v2 and v3**

```js
(tx_value >= 500000000000000000) && ((tx_logs_address == '0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f' && tx_logs_topic0 == '0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9') || (tx_logs_address == '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984' && tx_logs_topic0 == '0x783cca1c0412dd0d695e784568c96da2e9c22ff989357a2e8b1d9b2b4e6b7118'))
```

Deconstructing the expressions:

- `tx_value` checks for the ETH value of transactions **500000000000000000** in the above examples as the value needs to be mentioned in Wei.
- `tx_log_address` checks for the address of smart contract.
- `tx_logs_topic0` checks for the log topic0 of the emitted logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with web3.py by listening to PairCreated events emitted by the factory address and there after check whether this project launched with liquidity or not using Uniswap liquidity pool pair address abi to check for added liquidity amount.

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("Enter your Alchemy Node"))
uniswap_factory = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'
Uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads('Enter ABi')
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=Uniswap_factory_abi)
liquidityPairAddress = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2" #It's standard for most token to pair with WETH Address so we will be checking these pools.
lp_abi='Enter Uniswap v2 ABI' #Here is Uniswap V2 Address-0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D

def get_token_from_lp(lpAddres):
    uniswap_v2_pair = web3.eth.contract(address=lpAddres,abi=lp_abi)
    tokenA_address = uniswap_v2_pair.functions.token0().call()
    tokenB_address = uniswap_v2_pair.functions.token1().call()
    if tokenA_address == liquidityPairAddress:
       return 0
    elif tokenB_address ==liquidityPairAddress:
       return 1


def get_liquidity_balance(lp_address):
    lp_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=lp_address, abi=lp_abi)
    reserves = lp_contract.functions.getReserves().call()
    index= get_token_from_lp(lp_address)
    balance = reserves[index]
    return balance

event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.create_filter(fromBlock="latest")
while True:
    try:

        #events = event_filter.get_all_entries()
        events = event_filter.get_new_entries()

        if len(events) > 0:

           for event in events:
               if (event['args']['token1'] == liquidityPairAddress):
                   tokenAddress = event['args']['token0']
               

                   lp_address=contract.functions.getPair(tokenAddress,liquidityPairAddress).call()
   

                   lp_balance= get_liquidity_balance(lp_address)
               

                   tokenLiquidityAmount = float(web3.from_wei(lp_balance, "ether"))
                   print(f"Token Address: {tokenAddress}, Lp Amount{tokenLiquidityAmount}")
```

I hope this starter code get you going.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for Uniswap v3?

Comment: It's basically the same process just some slight changes in terms of router and factory address